# Is there a way to get a list of users currently logged in to CouchDB?

Tags: security, couchdb

I've had the suspicion that someone might be snooping around on my CouchDB with someone else's credentials but I'm not sure how to check at the server level.

I've tried to query through the `_session` api but it's not really designed to do that.

I'm open to looking into random files on the server, that would be an option for me.

I'm not ready to look into the CouchDB source code, but I will if that's what it comes to.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [View active user sessions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43254086/view-active-user-sessions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is. Start couchdb in the interactive mode with `sudo couchdb -i`

Now in the shell type

`ets:match(auth_by_user_ets,{'$1','_'})`  and you should get a result like

`[[<<"user1012">>],[<<"ABBA">>]]`

that is just the names of the authenticated users.

If you want a complete result set you can use

`ets:match(auth_by_user_ets,'$1')` the result will look like

```
[[{<<"user1012">>,
   {[{<<"_id">>,<<"org.couchdb.user:user1012">>},
     {<<"_rev">>,<<"1-495d19f995d985c52c8fbe4444a3e32d">>},
     {<<"password_scheme">>,<<"pbkdf2">>},
     {<<"iterations">>,10},
     {<<"name">>,<<"user1012">>},
     {<<"roles">>,[]},
     {<<"type">>,<<"user">>},
     {<<"derived_key">>,
      <<"84266c5c57e0efe15a50cc5a9a48a7af958ba2d1">>},
     {<<"salt">>,<<"c7acfd644bbcd37a79efd03712f48b7e">>}],
    {1414,563784,127875}}}],
 [{<<"ABBA">>,
   {[{<<"_id">>,<<"org.couchdb.user:ABBA">>},
     {<<"_rev">>,<<"1-6b00c9f9a5cd675310dbf50c46797c5a">>},
     {<<"password_scheme">>,<<"pbkdf2">>},
     {<<"iterations">>,10},
     {<<"name">>,<<"ABBA">>},
     {<<"roles">>,[]},
     {<<"type">>,<<"user">>},
     {<<"derived_key">>,
      <<"f11d5d89880438182c4ba4644cf47aafb0231ada">>},
     {<<"salt">>,<<"344780e9b0222613ea826c48804913df">>}],
    {1414,564902,847623}}}]]
```

`auth_by_user_ets` is an in memory cache that holds the list of authenticated users. The number of users held in the memory depend upon the `auth_cache_size` parameter in the `config` file. So you can set this parameter to a large number to accommodate the users in the `auth_by_user_ets` table.